# Insert tokens into a string dynamicaly Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of Array[String] that i want to transform into a list of String like this :

```
val sqlMap = mapList.map({case x => "INSERT INTO bddMedic VALUES ('"+x(0)+"','"+x(1)+"','"+x(2)+"','"+x(3)+"','"+x(4)+"','"+x(5)+"');"})
```

So i could generate my SQL request.
My problem is that i hardcode the number of element in my Array but the things is that sometimes there are 6 or 7 element in the array.

What i want is a code that would give me the String

> "INSERT INTO bddMedic VALUES ('"+x(0)+"','"+x(1)+"','"+x(2)+"','"+x(3)+"','"+x(4)+"','"+x(5)+"');"

(with the x(0) replaced by the value)
but without having to specify the x(0) x(1) x(2).
I realy have no idea on how to do it and every try is a failure.

Comment: I would recommend an SQL layer, such as https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie or http://squeryl.org/ or https://github.com/getquill/quill or http://slick.lightbend.com/

Comment: Yes. Really, really, don't build SQL like this.

Comment: Why is this bas

Comment: Why is this bad* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using mkString:

```
scala> val x = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
x: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> x.mkString(",")
res2: String = 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Yes i just found that x.mkString could do the job.

Comment: Dangerous if the array of strings is not coming from a trusted source (i.e. query string) as it is vulnerable to sql injection. I would recommend prepared statements instead.